# Can deformable part based model used for image classification?

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision

The info about DPM can be found at http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~rbg/latent/ . From the code provided by the site it is more used for object detection, so can it be used in combination of object detection and classification? For example, can it be used for bird detection on images and also tell what kind of this bird is.

Comment: It depends on what you consider "classification". In can, for example, classify an object as a dog, a car or a car. Determining the specific breed of the cat/dog would probably be too difficult for that algorithm. 

Does that help?

Comment: OK, then I'll write that as an answer if you don't mind

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you consider "classification". In can, for example, classify an object as a dog, a car or a car. Determining the specific breed of the cat/dog would probably be too difficult for that algorithm.